# Python 3 - Christmas tree code - syntax errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new to coding and I'm trying (and failing) to make a code that prints a Christmas-tree shape of "*" in whatever size instructed, and don't know where I'm going wrong, but I keep getting a variety of syntax errors all over my code.

```
size_raw = input("Size of tree?")

def spaces(length, size):
  Space = " "
  new_len = size / 2
  new_len -= length
  space_s = int(Space) * int(new_len)
  return space_s

def segment(h, tw, bw, s):
  line = tw
  star = "*"
  while line <= bw:
    stars = line * star
    print (spaces(int(line), int(s)) + (stars) + (spaces(int(line), int(s))
    line += 2

def tree(size):
  Topwidth = 1
  height = 3
  while Topwidth <= size:
    bottom_width = Topwidth + height
    segment(int(height), int(Topwidth), int(bottom_width), int(size)
    height += 2

 if size_raw == "Very Big":
     tree(100)
 elif size_raw == "Massive":
     tree(1000)
 else:
     tree(int(size_raw))
```

I expect it to work smoothly in this current state, however it responds with an error of a new for in a new location with each new attempt.

Comment: Hi Maple, It would be easy for people to answer, if you post the error as well along with your expected output.

Comment: Can you post the error that you are getting? Indentation isn't regular in the program that you posted. And can you add sample input and output?

Comment: In your `tree` function - you check for `Topwidth` in your `while` condition but you never update `Topwidth`. This will be an infinite loop. Also, as an aside - please read the PEP-8 guidelines to name your variables better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parenthesis are not closed properly.

Your code

```
print (spaces(int(line), int(s)) + (stars) + (spaces(int(line), int(s))
segment(int(height), int(Topwidth), int(bottom_width), int(size)
```

My version

```
print (spaces(int(line), int(s))) + (stars) + (spaces(int(line), int(s)))
segment(int(height), int(Topwidth), int(bottom_width), int(size))
```

Got it to work with this [fiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/f3681cf1-5858-4b5d-87fe-5c41b27ea4a5/?i=true), where i also change the indention to be with 4 spaces which is the most common indention.